# User avatar cropping/resizing with paperclip and jquery in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am building my first Ruby on Rails app which is going to be my own little community.
I have made the User model with several fields and information.

Now I am thinking of adding avatar support for the users. I've been researching and found that my best option would be using [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), but then I encountered a little dilemma.

I want my users to be able to resize/crop their avatar image after they have chosen a image.
I have Googled a lot and since i am using jQuery i found that [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) would be best in my opinion. And i think [MiniMagick](http://rubyforge.org/projects/mini-magick/) looks best.

So to my question. How can I best integrate Paperclip and imgAreaSelect?
I am new to Ruby and Rails so i don't know how i can resize the image.

Do you folks know how to integrate the to or maybe some other options that fits my needs best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ryan Bates covered cropping images using Paperclip and JCrop in [Railscast 182](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images). I'd recommend that you check it out.

Comment: This episode has been updated http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised